# Hiding the scrollbar for a listbox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Please let me know how i can hide the scrollbar from being displayed in Silverlight.
I dont want vertical or horizontal scrollbar. i want to hide both . PLease help

Answer (score 8):

You can set the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and/or ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility attached properties to "Disabled".  For example, if you have the following XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="100" Name="listBox1" Width="100">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="50" Fill="#FF894220" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="50" Fill="#FFB94222" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

You will therefore get scrollbars, like so:

*[Unfortunately StackOverflow won't let me post the images until I get a higher reputation (which I'm trying to build).  You'll have to imagine it or try it yourself]*

Adding the ScrollViewer attached properties to the ListBox element:

```
<ListBox Height="100" Name="listBox1" Width="100"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="50" Fill="#FF894220" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="50" Fill="#FFB94222" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

results in no scrollbars.

Hope this helps...

Chris